# Losing the Undo option when sending DELETE from within a Word VBA routine

Tags: vba, ms-word, undo

I have an application which allows the user to place data (using a SET field) within a document which describes information about the contents of the document.  This information needs to be difficult for the average user of the document to see it, hence my use of the SET field and needs to be located near the location of the information in the document..

I want to trap the fact that a user may be copying, cutting or deleting this field in the normal course of editing the document.  I have been able to code the copying and cutting operations so that I detect if the field is present in the user’s selection. (If it is there, I issue a warning and ask for permission to proceed.)  I am currently having a problem with the Delete key and it occurs whether a field is present or not.  Having set up a KeyBinding, the delete key is trapped and my routine is called.  If it is a normal delete, I turn off the KeyBinding and use SENDKEYS to send a DELETE to delete the characters or selection.  Finally, here is the problem, there is no Undo for this operation including when there is no field to delete.  So basically, the Undo operation is no longer available for the delete key.  Does anyone have an idea as to how to overcome this?  I could, I suppose, populate the Undo stack but that would entail placing bookmarks all over the place to do so – not an appealing option. The KeyBinding:

```
 With Application
    If Not lOn Then 'clear the key binding
        'blnCatchBackspace = False
        FindKey(nKey).Clear
    Else 'apply the key binding
        'blnCatchBackspace = True
        .CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument
        .KeyBindings.Add KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
            Command:="cRoutine", _
            KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyDelete)
    End If
End With
```

and the simple delete code:

```
Call ToggleCatch(False)  'Remove the delete key binding
SendKeys "{DELETE}"
DoEvents
Call ToggleCatch(True)   ' Turn the delete key binding on
```

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong but VBA cannot be undone with the undo button. You need to add it to the vba code. But you will be limited and it wont track multiple instances, it will only keep the last interface I believe ```application.undo```

Comment: @SublimizeD VBA actions "are* recorded in Word's Undo list - they appear under the button. But certain actions will *empty* the list, such as protecting or unprotecting a document as a form.

Comment: Have you considered using Document `Variable`s for storing information, rather than `Set` fields? Their content can be displayed in `DocVariable` fields. Or put the information in a CustomXMLPart (more "modern", but also more work).

Comment: Another possibility other than Document Variables and Custom XML parts might be to put the SET field in a content control that you have marked as “Cannot be deleted”. Then hide the control, if necessary.

Comment: Cindy and Yokki, the nature of the problem is such that the SET field needs to be close to where the data is.  The operations involve an author writing a report that contains data.  Someone else needs to come in a verify that the data is correct by going to the original source supplied by the author. When these operations are being done, I add color coded hidden text adjacent to the set field that allows these users to see the information and the source.  I toggle between showing the hidden text and not and when the file is saved all of the hidden text is removed.

Comment: Cindy and Yokki (continued), I have thought about using Document variables but I would still have to put a bookmark where the data is and if the user wants to delete the data, the bookmark seems to stay after the delete.  So I get into the same issue.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Cindy and SublimizeD, thanks.  Some things are saved in the Undo stack.  For example, when I trap the Cut command and I complete it with a Selection.Cut, it works.  However, the code I got from this forum did have an unprotect command in it and I didn't remove it.  I will let you know if that solves the problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Cindy, you hit the nail on the head.  I removed the activedocument.Protect commands and the Undo stack is active.  Thanks.  I guess I need some more reputation points to indicate that it is the right answer since I haven't found how to do it.